# What alternatives exist to Spring Batch to handle queued jobs?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, scheduled-tasks, application-server, spring-batch

I have been looking in to Spring Batch to solve a batch processing scenario with huge amount of data involved in each job. Are there any other solutions that compete with Spring Batch? To be used in a Java EE environment.

Comment: I think https://camunda.com/ can also be used as an alternative. you can use Camunda Platform 7 as an embedded engine to orchestrate their Java code (using Spring Boot or Tomcat)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the uber-king of big-data batch processing is [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/), but that can be rather tricky to set up, to put it mildly.

Answer (score 7):

Batch support is now available in Java EE 7 via [JSR 352: Batch applications for the Java platform](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=352).

See [Batch Applications in Java EE 7 - Undertanding JSR 352 Concepts](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/batch_applications_in_java_ee) for some more info.

Answer (score 4):

There is also JobRunr - It is a port of Hangfire to Java.

It allows to schedule simple Java 8 lamdbda's as follows:

```java
BackgroundJob.enqueue(() -> System.out.println("this will be done in a background process, perhaps even on a different server"));
```

More info on https://www.jobrunr.io or https://github.com/jobrunr/jobrunr.

P.s.: I'm the creator of JobRunr so I might be biased.

Comment: hello, is there anyway to try batch processing without purchasing? it is good if there is key and expires after 1 week. i compare same task by using spring batch and jobrunr-spring-boot-starter in terms of usage and time complexity

Comment: Please mail me at hello@jobrunr.io to see what we can work out.

Comment: @rdehuyss Is it possible to combine Spring Batch with JobRunr?

Comment: @trshiv: I think it would be possible (I haven't tried it, though), but I don't see the added value of combining the 2 of them.

Answer (score 3):

Akka is a nice solution too for precessing small tasks http://akka.io/

Answer (score 3):

Try easyBatch. The simple stupid Batch framework. 
Try it once and use it forever.
https://github.com/j-easy/easy-batch